# Getting an error while updating form state using mutator react final form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form, mutators, react-final-form-arrays

i am trying to update the values in the form state using react final form mutators by writing function below

```
const setProjectSelectedMutator = ([value], formState, tools) => {
tools.changeValue(formState, () => value && value.isSelectedInProject === true);
};
```

and then i am calling that mutate function like as below,

```
if (!once) {
    if (
      form &&
      values.spaceType.mechanicalData[mappedLibrarySourceArray] &&
      values.spaceType.mechanicalData[mappedLibrarySourceArray][index]
    ) {
      //  values.spaceType.mechanicalData[mappedLibrarySourceArray][
      //    index
      //  ].isSelectedInProject = true;
      form.mutators.setProjectSelectedMutator(
        values.spaceType.mechanicalData[mappedLibrarySourceArray][index].isSelectedInProject
      );
      setOnce(true);
    }
  }
```

i would like to set the boolean to true using the mutator function like as i am setting the same(mentioned in commented code) and getting an error like `mutate is not a function`.

I am new to react final forms and could any one please suggest any idea or suggestion on this issue.

Thanks in advance

Comment: any one have any idea on this why i am getting an error

Comment: Can you reproduce that in a sandbox?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the second parameter that has the name of the field. I'ved added the `"SOME NAME"` string to your code.

```
const setProjectSelectedMutator = ([value], formState, tools) => {
tools.changeValue(formState, "SOME NAME", () => value && value.isSelectedInProject === true);
};
```